# Excel 2010 formula to delete repeated content based on value (instead of second highest the lowest)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I've read a Question topic about picking the second highest value. I need the same but a bit different:

[Excel 2010 formula to delete repeated content based on value](https://superuser.com/questions/656217/excel-2010-formula-to-delete-repeated-content-based-on-value)

Maybe it is a bit rude, but I don't have enough points to reply on a topic, and I really want to know more about how it works.

I am working on a project and need to pick (instead of the second highest) the lowest value. What do I have to change in the formula to get this as a result?

Sorry for my poor English, it is not my mother language.. ;-)

Thanks for the clear and good explanation in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
=OR(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$18,A2)=1,SUMPRODUCT(1*(B2>$B$2:$B$18),1*(A2=$A$2:$A$18))=1)
```

You need to change the direction. It needs to be one position higher than the lowest not one position lower than the highest.
Rereading the post led me to believe OP looks for the lowest value. In this case you're looking for the value 0 position from the lowest (*...))=0)*), though in this case you'd be better off with some simpler syntaxes; unless you're  running hundreds of thousands of records nevermind.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clear explanation! I used the 0, wanted to have the lowest value. I had a lot of records, so this was definitely the easiest way. Many thanks, all solved now!

Answer (score 0):

I think most elegant way to do this with a pivot table: Set your name column as column label, set your number column as values and select to summarise it by minimum.